# Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ']' is not a valid attribute name. angular 4

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ']' is not a valid attribute name.
```

I simply made model:

```
export interface ModalComponentModel {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    password2: string;
    description: string;
}
```

I used it in my component:

component:

```
model: ModalComponentModel;
```

Then I tried to use it in my html file:

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Edit Profile</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <form class="form" role="form" (ngSubmit)="whatDoesThisFormDo()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Your username"
                           [(ngModel)]="model.username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Your password"
                           [(ngModel)]="model.password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Your password"
                           [(ngModel)]="model.password2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="model.description"]></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <button value="update" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Update</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <button value="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Cancel</button>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
```

It was working fine until I added to model, full HTML is above as requested.

I am also not able to get the buttons correctly side by side.

Comment: error is from somwhere else, post the full html

Comment: It should not have any error. Maybe it is somewhere else.

Comment: @micronyks full HTML attached

Comment: @Sajeetharan full html attached.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

`[(ngModel)]="model.description"]`      // ']' is added unnecessarily

change it to

`[(ngModel)]="model.description"`

Don't wrap it to a square bracket.

**Update:**

You can initialize your `model` variable as follow according to your need,

```
model:ModalComponentModel=<ModalComponentModel>{};
```

OR

```
model:ModalComponentModel=<ModalComponentModel>[];
```

Comment: Good catch but now it says `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`

Comment: its the same answer given below

Answer (score 17):

Problem is in this line

Change

**From**

```
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="model.description"]></textarea>
```

**to**

```
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="model.description"></textarea>
```

Comment: Good catch but now it says `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`

Comment: use safe operator model?.username or set model:ModalComponentModel=[];

Comment: I just posted a new copy as I was partially aware that a new error will be there. Drew will ask a new problem.

Comment: @Drew1208 ^^^^^

Answer (score 8):

You have problem in this line of code:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="model.description"]></textarea>
```

It should be:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="model.description"></textarea>
```

There is an extra bracket that is causing this error.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was `<app-some-component []></app-some-component>`. The empty `[]` was causing the issue.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I didn't close `]` in ngModel. I used the wrong code.

```
[(ngModel)="selectedTestName"
```

**Correct Syntax:**

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedTestName"
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a 0 inserted in a table element's attributes list. So the dom was trying to treat 0 as an attribute of table. Removing it fixed the issue. Two people spent 3 hours searching for the bug.

```
<table style="width:100%" 0>
```

Answer (score 4):

Having a comma in the wrong place also results in this issue:

```
<span>
[(ngModel)]="item",
(click)="onClick()"
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten this error from a typo  when trying to add an attribute to a directives host.

```
@Directive({
  ...
  host: {    
    '[style.touchAction' <-- missing closing bracket : '"none"',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't add any unuseful letters, brackets, commas, or any other thing,
You will face the same issue.

example:

```html
<h1 *ngIf="check" ,><h1>
```

In my case the `,` will give the same error

Comment: I just noticed I had 0 in my tag. Invalid attributes also leads to this erro

Comment: I should be thanking you, you saved me a lot of debugging, I hate console errors

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '()' is not a valid attribute name.

I had an extra () in my HTML which caused the issue.

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" () accept=".xml">
```

This code works fine as a html but Angular uses renderer to manipulate the DOM with ceratin set of functions like setAttribute, setProperty, etc.,

Renderer literally parses the HTML text and try to set the attributes for a html tag, In this process it throws an error when it identifies any invalid syntax/ extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[' is not a valid attribute name.

For this error is generate by many thing but i was get is in 2 case

1. If your tag is not close in one line of [   src]=""

in upper html i did not close src [ in same line so i showing error
2. if you are not close [src] proper close .

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue because `[` and `attributeName` are not on the same line. My manual formatting sent the attribute name on the next line. That is the reason for the test case failure.

Just make sure your `[attributeName]="value"` should on the same line to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of comment closing tag `-->` left inside of component selector tag

```
    <app-my-component-name [alignment]="'absolute'" --> // HERE
         [customClass]="'foo'">
    </app-my-component-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra ']' probably came from autocomplete. It has happened more than once for me.